# any built in switch for switching between IG and Discrete graphics for bumblebee

Tags: nvidia, graphics, bumblebee

I have installed BUMBLEBEE. Everytime i want to run an application, i need to use the keyword OPTIRUN. Is there a way to load the application using nvidia card whenever it is needed automatically? I mean without using the keyword OPTIRUN in terminal (It's a headache to run every application by typing)

Thanks for your replies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is covered in the following article at the Steam Support website. The following link will take you to the article. [**"Optimus and Steam for Linux"**](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6316-GJKC-7437). It will still require some manual editing but you should be able to accomplish this through the Steam launcher. Optimus support is still in it's infancy but is steadily getting better. I was originally a long term Ubuntu user but switched to Arch Linux after failing to get Ubuntu to work correctly with my muxless Optimus laptop, Hope this helps.